# Bootstrap Card Padding Without Exceeding Borders

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a web app which will work on a 800 x 480 pixel screen on full screen mode.
My App is single page app using ReactJS and it has a simple Navigation Bar at top, and 4 Bootstrap Card with 2x2 arrangement.
Code is like:

```html
<div class="nav-bar">Component</div>
<div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card-body"> Something-1</div>
    <div class="card-body"> Something-2</div>
</div>
<div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card-body"> Something-3</div>
    <div class="card-body"> Something-4</div>
</div>
```

Problem is that, Something-3 and Something-4 cards has something in them(!) which exceeds my 480 px limit. Is there any solution that changes the tightness of card without changing margins and padding of the ingredients of card?

Comment: Your snippet doesn't show what actually happens. To create an [mcve], you can import the Bootstrap CSS, and should show some kind of example of the content you have in the cards that take up too much space.

Comment: You ' re so right, I'm a newcomer to stackOverflow, next time I will keep that link in mind, thanks for your warning and glad that there people which are philanthropist like you :^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `.card-body` classes come directly under your `.card-deck` class; you're missing the core `.card` class in between.

Your `.card-deck` should contain **multiple** `.card` elements, which are the core **[Bootstrap cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card)** themselves. These `.card` elements **contain** the `.card-body` (which in turn usually contain the classes `.card-title` and `.card-text`).

If set up correctly, it doesn't matter how much content a card has in it; it will simply overflow to contain it.

This can be seen in the following:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus convallis auctor accumsan. Cras eu purus quis dui tempus finibus. Quisque et suscipit mi. Mauris maximus nisi vitae blandit interdum. Etiam interdum felis nec sapien tristique, nec sollicitudin urna ornare. Integer magna orci, scelerisque at fermentum nec, tempor id purus. Phasellus suscipit tempus odio, sit amet aliquam arcu varius at. Sed rutrum pellentesque tortor, id pharetra ante euismod nec. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus convallis auctor accumsan. Cras eu purus quis dui tempus finibus. Quisque et suscipit mi. Mauris maximus nisi vitae blandit interdum. Etiam interdum felis nec sapien tristique, nec sollicitudin urna ornare. Integer magna orci, scelerisque at fermentum nec, tempor id purus. Phasellus suscipit tempus odio, sit amet aliquam arcu varius at. Sed rutrum pellentesque tortor, id pharetra ante euismod nec. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thnx bro, with a little extra touches that helped me a lot. I will give u my ratings when I reach the enough reputation. Keep up the good work, thank you so much !